# Multiple samples in Stata

Tags: stata, random

I have a dataset with 40k entries and would like to get 100 samples of 400 entries and then analyze those samples in Stata. I know this is an extremely basic question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere on the internet. Anyone would like to help me out?

Comment: Start here: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/random-samples/

Comment: Why the emphasis on looking at the internet? Start with Stata's own documentation, help and manual.

Answer (score 2):

For sampling with replacement, use `bsample`.

For sampling without replacement, use `sample`.

You might also find this FAQ on [writing you own bootstrap command](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-do-i-write-my-own-bootstrap-program/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Set a seed of your choice, generate random numbers and then shuffle according to those. You now have 100 disjoint samples of size 400.

```
set seed 2803 
gen double random = runiform()
sort random
egen sampleid = seq(), block(400)
```

Comment: I believe that should be `sort random`. Correct?